# How can I access variables in packed structure without unaligned mode?

Tags: c, struct, structure, padding, packing

I'm using packed structure for communication using direct DMA access, and here is my test code:

```
// structure for communication buf 1
typedef __packed struct _test1
{
    uint8_t a;
    uint32_t b;
    uint16_t c;
    uint16_t d;
    uint32_t e;
} test1;

// structure for communication buf 2
.
.
.
// structure for communication buf 3
.
.
.

// structure for communication buf set
typedef __packed struct _test2
{
    uint8_t dump[3];
    test1 t;
    // may have many other packed structure for communication buf
} test2;

#pragma anon_unions

typedef struct _test3
{
    union
    {
        uint32_t buf[4];
        __packed struct
        {
            __packed uint8_t dump[3];
            test1 t;
        };
    };
} test3;

test1 t1;
test2 t2;
test3 t3;
```

size of these structures are

```
sizeof(t1) = 13
sizeof(t2) = 16
sizeof(t3) = 16
```

if I want to access variable b, for not effecting performance, read/write memory content with aligned access is needed, with calculated offset by hand

```
t3.buf[1]
```

but I cannot read/write variables in structure without using unaligned accesses

```
t2.t.b
t3.t.b
```

so I defined structures like the following code, packed only variable a

```
typedef struct _test4
{
    __packed uint8_t a;
    uint32_t b;
    uint16_t c;
    uint16_t d;
    uint32_t e;
} test4;

typedef struct _test5
{
    __packed uint8_t dump[3];
    test4 t;
} test5;

test4 t4;
test5 t5;
```

although access of all element in structure is aligned, but padding is inserted either

```
sizeof(t4) = 16
sizeof(t5) = 20
```

so how can I define packed structures, and access single variable in it without using unaligned access(except a)?

thanks a lot for helping

Comment: Packing is vendor dependent - which compiler/operating system/chipset are you using

Comment: keil arm compiler v5.06 / no embedded os / freescale kv series

Comment: Even if it  often looks very tempting to overlay C `structs` over structured data received from somewhere, it typically leads to many more problems than it solves and is generally not a very good idea. Receive the bytes into a plain byte buffer and build your structures from there.

Comment: It is an enclosed environment, there is no need to worry about rebuild structure when receive, but there is so much data to be transfer/save, I need to reduce my structure size in case of not not effecting performance if possible

Answer (score 4):

Your question introduces two problems under the umbrella of one:

- Communication between components and/or devices; this may or may not have the same underlying representation of structures and integers, hence your use of the non-portable `__packed` attribute.
- Performance of access, biased by alignment and/or data size; on one hand the compiler aligns data to fall in line with the bus, yet on the other hand that data might occupy too much space in your cache.

One of these is the actual problem you want to solve, X, and the other the Y in [your XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please avoid asking XY problems in the future.

Have you considered how to guarantee that `uint16_t` and `uint32_t` will be big endian or little endian, based on your requirements? You need to specify that, if you care about portability. I care about portability, so that's what my answer will focus on. You may also notice how optimal efficiency will be obtained, too. Nonetheless, to make this portable:

- You *should* be serialising your data using serialisation functions to convert each member of your structure into sequences of bytes by *division* and *modulo* (or *left shift* and *binary and*) operations.
- Similarly, you should be deserialising your data by inverse operations *multiplication* and *addition* (or *right shift* and *binary or*).

As an example, here's some code showing both *little endian* and *big endian* for serialising and deserialising `test1`:

```
typedef /*__packed*/ struct test1
{
    uint32_t b;
    uint32_t e;
    uint16_t c;
    uint16_t d;
    uint8_t a;
} test1;

void serialise_test1(test1 *destination, void *source) {
    uint8_t *s = source;
    destination->a = s[0];
    destination->b = s[1] * 0x01000000UL
                   + s[2] * 0x00010000UL
                   + s[3] * 0x00000100UL
                   + s[4];                 /* big endian */
    destination->c = s[5] * 0x0100U
                   + s[6];                 /* big endian */
    destination->d = s[7]
                   + s[8] * 0x0100U;       /* little endian */
    destination->e = s[9]
                   + s[10] * 0x00000100UL
                   + s[11] * 0x00010000UL
                   + s[12] * 0x01000000UL; /* little endian */
}

void deserialise_test1(void *destination, test1 *source) {
    uint8_t temp[] = { source->a
                     , source->b >> 24, source->b >> 16
                                      , source->b >> 8, source->b
                     , source->c >> 8, source->c
                     , source->d, source->d >> 8
                                , source->d >> 16, source->b >> 24 };
    memcpy(destination, temp, sizeof temp);
}
```

---

You may notice that I removed the `__packed` attribute and rearranged the members, so that the larger members precede (i.e. come before) the smaller; this is likely to reduce padding significantly. The functions allow you to convert between an array of `uint8_t` (which you send to/receive from *the wire*, or *DMA*, or whatnot) and your `test1` structure, so this code is much more *portable*. You benefit from the guarantees this code provides regarding the structure of your protocol, where-as before it was at the whim of the implementation, and two devices using two different implementations might have *disagreed* about the internal representation of integers for example.

Comment: Why didn't you use `<<` instead of multiplying by those numbers?

Comment: sorry for not described my question clearly, it is an enclosed environment, there is no need to worry about endian or portable problem, the reason speak of communication is because that I have a lot data to transfer(same as saving data to eeprom), so it is important to reduce my structure size as far as possible :)

Comment: The multiplication could be a bad idea, since this enforces a needlessly large type promotion based on the right operand. With shift, the result is that of the promoted left operand and the type of the right operand does not affect the result. Now as it happens this was a 32 bit MCU and unsigned long is likely 32 bit, but on a 8 or 16 bit MCU this would result in needlessly poor performance.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya To demonstrate that either operation could be used, I should've shown both (as I did with big/little endian). The multiplication can be helpful to visualise for some from a mathematical point, as some people don't understand left/right shifts.

Comment: @Lundin Promotion to 32-bit types is unavoidable there because the deserialised types *are* 32 bits. Whether the promotion occurs before or after the shifts, it still occurs *before* the additions; it has to, or else the result is incorrect. You're talking about a whole four or so instructions, but I'll correct that tomorrow when I edit the code with Ajays suggestion in mind.

Comment: @Lundin even if it was 8 or 16 bit and the result is assigned to a variable of 8 bit (or 16). The promotion and downcast will be a NOP. Any *acceptable* compiler would replace it with left shift and on smaller width only.

Comment: To clarify, those four instructions will still exist in the shift-version; they might just change to use a different register... That may also have negative consequences, as serialisation and deserialisation aren't usually significant bottlenecks. Higher-performance registers should be favoured for significant bottlenecks. For example, if on such a system with such a project there's also 16-bit checksum code, that's likely to be more crucial for register selection. This micro-optimisation idea... -sighs-

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya This is memory-mapped data for DMA. For that to work, the data must be volatile qualified. Meaning that the compiler is _not_ allowed to optimize a 32 bit read/write into a 8/16 bit one. Now of course every answer has failed to point out the missing `volatile`, but the OP did say that this memory was for DMA.

Comment: @Seb I take it you have never disassembled 32 bit arithmetic on a 8-bit MCU. It is not "micro-optimization", we are talking of a wall of several hundred extra instructions in machine code, likely including extra function calls etc. The 8 bit MCU can store bytes just fine inside a 32 bit chunk, but when you tell it to perform _32 bit arithmetic_ you bloat the code with enormous overhead.

Comment: From experience, that is almost never used in the linux kernel (vmxnet3 with `struct UPT1_RSSConf`, even packed isn't used)

Answer (score 0):

You could hard code all the indexes like

```
    typedef __packed struct _test1
    {
        uint8_t a;
        uint32_t b;
        uint16_t c;
        uint16_t d;
        uint32_t e;
    } test1;

    enum
    {
        a = 0,
        b = 1,
        c = 5,
        d = 7,
        e = 9,
    };

    test1 t1 = {1,2,3,4};//not sure if init lists work for packed values
    printf("%u", *(uint32_t*)((uint8_t*)&t1 + b));
```

Or offsetof can be used like this

```
printf("%u", *(uint32_t*)((uint8_t*)&t1 + offsetof(test1, b)));
```

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Yeah, you could use that as well.

Comment: There is a lot of variables in structure, and lot of structure for using, it will be a vary hard job to calculate every offset by hand or using offsetof, and it will make me feel like crying if I have to insert a new variable in it, so I may not take this into consideration :)

Comment: @ChihWen what would be the problem with using `offsetof`. You wont have to change the code even after inserting new variables in between

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya In this method, I have to deal with types of every variables when using, and will have to search for code using this variable when changing type of it, it may complicated the problem, most of all, I want to find if there is a simple way to access in a packed structure :)

Comment: `%d` should *only* correspond with expressions of type `int`. You probably meant `printf ("%"PRIu32, ...` or something like that... and use of magic numbers is commonly frowned upon. Perhaps you could find a way to use `offsetof` to calculate those magic numbers, or even to circumvent the `enum` altogether... idk, seems cleaner to me that way, but... I'm no expert.